# jQuery: Jump to anchor tag from dropdown (selection) box?

Tags: jquery, select, anchor, dropdown

I have searched and havent been able to get any of the solutions to work. (and I'm not 100% clear why?)

I am dynamically building a dropdown (select) box...

adding a matching anchor tag name (number) to the value of each option in the select box.

I have some jQuery to watch for any change in the select box and 'jump' to marching anchor tag/name...

But it is not working.

Depending on the approach I try and I get these errors:

```
TypeError: $(...).offset(...) is undefined      

$("html, body").animate({scrollTop: $('#' + $(this).val()).offset().top}, "slow"...
```

or:

```
Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: ##15
```

when I have the # in the jQuery statement and without:

Question 1:  Should I put the # in the option entry value?  or keep it appending in the jQuery statement?

jQuery:

```
$('#topic_entries').change(function(){                                  
            //populate fields with video details            
            if($('#topic_entries option:selected').text() == 'No Videos Found'){
                //do nothing (dead)     
            }else{
                var targetAnchor = $(this).val();
                console.log(targetAnchor);              
                //$('html,body').animate({scrollTop: targetAnchor}, 'slow');
                //$('html, body').animate({'scrollTop': $(targetAnchor).top}, 2000);        
                //$('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $(targetAnchor).offset().top}, 1000);
                $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $('#' + $(this).val()).offset().top}, "slow");

            }
        });
```

What am I missing here?  I just want to have a simple 'jump to anchor' feature executed from the dropdown selection (value)

Missing HTML portion:

```
for($i=0; $i<count($results); $i++){
    //update currentTopic
    $currentTopic = $results[$i]['topic'];
    echo '<option value="'.$i.'">' . $currentTopic . '</option>';
    //echo '<option value="#'.$i.'">' . $currentTopic . '</option>';
}
```

==============================================

Solution update:

Well it seems a quick and simple fix was to use this line instead:

```
window.location.hash = targetAnchor;
```

But I am curious as to why none of the jQuery attempts worked for me?  (ie: what was I doing in-correctly?)

Comment: Show us the HTML part, my crystal ball reports nothing.

Comment: @ViRuSTriNiTy 

fair enough (although I have verified it is correct (Firebug) and all 'values' are correct)

    `for($i=0; $i<count($results); $i++){      
       $currentTopic = $results[$i]['topic'];
       echo '<option value="'.$i.'">' . $currentTopic . '</option>';
       //echo '<option value="#'.$i.'">' . $currentTopic . '</option>'; 
     }`

Comment: Did you render you anchors with an id attribute like `<a id="foo"></a>` ?

Comment: ahh....

That must be it.. 

No.  I was using named anchors (like normal).. and guess I just glazed over the # in the jquery line as meaning for the anchor/hash.. and NOT meaning an ID)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to render the anchors with an id attribute like

```
<a id="foo"></a>
```

Also ensure that `$(this).val()` in your jQuery selection `$('#' + $(this).val())` returns the value of the id attribute only to get the jQuery selector right, e.g. `#foo` as shown in the anchor above.

Comment: accepted as answer to the original jQuery approach question.